# NaN in SQLite3 have invalid numerical comparisons

Tags: sqlite

I have some records in a REAL column which register as NaNs. I understand there is no specific storage value for NaNs in SQLite, that these are just stored as text, but in any case there should be a reasonable numerical comparisons on those values

```
sqlite> select post,val from trainer_npos5_3_scored where key='FER201008214' and val<0.06;
sqlite> select post,val from trainer_npos5_3_scored where key='FER201008214' and val>0.06;
1|0.07023458
3|0.1461988
4|0.08926977
6|NaN
2|0.1489425
5|0.0628851721249876
sqlite>
```

So when I ask for values > 0.06 I get the NaN and when I ask for values less then I do not get it. 0.0628 is the minimum here.

How can I deal with NaNs with some consistency in SQLite3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite treats NaN values as `NULL`.  (This conversion is done in the internal function `sqlite3VdbeMemSetDouble`.)

What it seems is happening is that your column is storing the *string* `'NaN'` instead of `NULL`.  The result of the comparison is determined by [an arbitrary rule](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#comparisons) that numbers are less than strings.

If you prefer 3VL behavior, where `val<0.06` and `val>0.06` both return `NULL` and so your queries don't select those rows, execute the command:

```
UPDATE trainer_npos5_3_scored SET val = NULL WHERE val LIKE 'NaN'
```

Comment: Yes! thanks. After posting I realized that all NaN are larger than any number. The NaNs come about from Perl via DBD::SQLite module. I have to look at that in more detail